# How to use a single script for multiple frames

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, adobe

I've build a topotrainer in Flash consisting of 50 states.
For every state I made a frame. The code of these 50 frames should be the same for all, while the graphics defer. If I put the code on the first of the 50 frames it is only working there. If I put the code at every frame I get a lot of errors, because all the functions are doublated.

**Is there a way for all the 52 frames to run the same code?**

Thanks for your time,

More info:

[image]

The red square is indicating the 50 states. That is pure graphicly.
I made a seperate layer for all the coding.
The blue circle indicates the (working) code for one single state-frame.
All the 50 graphical frames want to use this code. 
@Atriace: is your explanation solving this particular problem?

Thanks,

Justin

Comment: Updated.  I believe this should answer your question.  Also note that whether the frames exist (on the layer with the code) all the way to the end of the USMap is not important, but rather whether the playhead has read from the frame yet.  I'm uncertain what would happen if you skipped the frame, but I suspect it would fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

The important thing to be aware with frames is that things don't exist until after they're initialized.  Assume that on `Frame1` we have the blue square, and on `Frame2` we have the red circle.

[image: Example]

The play-head starts on the left and works its way to the right.  As it arrives at each frame, it then creates whatever it finds there for it, be it a symbol or code.  This means that if we try to hook up the red circle with an event listener on `Frame1` it will fail; naturally because red circle hasn't been created yet.

```
stop();

function hello(e:Event):void {
    var destination:int = (currentFrame == 1) ? 2 : 1;
    trace("Hello " + e.currentTarget.name + ": " + currentFrame + " of " + totalFrames + " > " + destination)
    gotoAndStop(destination)
}

BlueSquare.addEventListener("click", hello);
RedCircle.addEventListener("click", hello); // <<< this will fail
```

However, if we put that single line on the same frame as when the red circle is created, it will link to `hello()` correctly and run.

[image: Example 2]

Comment: Hey Atriace, thanks for your fast response! I edited my post as I am not sure if we are on the same line. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Thanks again. But I guess that is not my problem. If I copy the code 50 times, so that every frame has the same code. It gives me the error of defining the same function multiple times. Do you know how to solve that?

Comment: You really should not copy the code 50 times.  You can create it on the first frame, and reference it from those other frames.  The example is above.  If you wish, I would be happy to take a look at your fla file, but I'm not sure how else to clarify this.

Comment: Wauw, you're the best. And I'm a noob in actionscript 3 :)

I put the code parts consisting of functions in the first frame and only put the addEventListeners in the 50 frames. Now it totally works!

Comment: So you advice me to do my whole project within one frame next time in stead of making a frame for every country/state?

Comment: Indubitably.  As irony would have it, I recently made a country map in Flash (http://i.stack.imgur.com/ivHlb.jpg).  You can see the DisplayList on the left.  Everything is on one frame.  There's no need for frames, once you handle animations with libraries like Greensock's TweenLite (https://greensock.com/tweenlite-as).